# How can I replace variable names across files?

Tags: atom-editor

I am using atom as editor. I'd like to replace variable names across files. I've replaced `jpy_usd` by `usd_jpy`. I want to do that to all occurrences of `jpy_usd` in my rails project. Could you tell me if you know how to do it?

Comment: `CMD + CTRL + G` selects all of current selected word or phrase within the same file. `CMD + SHIFT + F` finds all of a certain word or phrase in your directory and lists all the locations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to find word 'jpy_usd' by using this shortcut

```
cmd-shift-f
```

Then you can click replace all after fill the word that you want to replace.

Refer image below
[image]

You may refer to [here](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following way.

1. type cmd+shift+f, then search all of `jpy_usd` in my project
2. move to one file
3. select one `jpy_usd` word, then type cmd+d in order to select the others `jpy_usd` in the same file. Thus edit them simultaneously
4. contine 2 & 3